# Update status of test case in ALM

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, alm

I am trying to update the status of the test cases in ALM to Passed.Had written Java code using OTA API to update the status in QC , but understand the same will not work for ALM.

What would be the way to get a handle of test cases in ALM and update the status of test cases to Passed

Comment: What version of ALM?

Comment: For both ALM and QC, OTA code will remain same. Its just about registering dlls on the machine where your code is going to execute. Code written for QC 10 version should run in all the versions till 12.20 any edition. I have bunch of code written in .net which executes against all the versions.

Even if you are using com4j or jinterop, its all about registering correct dlls on the client machine.

Answer (score -2):

Check the proxy connection and also share the coding details.